# Replacing class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have inserted a disabled button on my website and I want it to get enabled when another enabled button is clicked. I have written the code for it.

**CODE** ( Materialize CSS )

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("btnn").classList.replace("btn disabled",
    "waves-effect waves-light btn");

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">

    </div>
  </nav>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div align="middle" hspace="30>
      

      <a href=" https://vimeo.com/271908370 "><font size="4 ">Click </font> <a 
      class="btn disabled " id ="btnn ">Skip Ad</a> </a><font size="4 "> to skip 
      the ad and play the video.</font>
    </a> 
    </p>
    <br>

    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/271908370? autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0 " width="640 " height="360 " 
    frameborder="0 " webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>

     <br>

      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn " id="btn ">button</a>



      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript " src="js/materialize.min.js "></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, this did not work. The disabled button remained disabled even after clicking the enabled button. I don't know where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should update your HTML, it's unreadable, missing several closing tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace()` can only be used to replace one class with another, you can't give it multiple classes. If you want to replace multiple classes, use `.remove()` and `.add()`.

You also had extra spaces in the `id` attributes in your HTML. `id="btnn "` should be `id="btn"`. This was causing `document.getElementById()` to fail.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("btnn").classList.remove("disabled");
  document.getElementById("btnn").classList.add("waves-effect", "waves-light");

})
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: grey;
}

.waves-effect {
  color: yellow;
}

.waves-light {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn disabled" id="btnn">Skip Ad</a> </a>
<br>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btn">button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was throwing an error because `classList.replace` method can't contain multiple classes (spaces actually). To solve your problem, you have to call `classList.remove` and `classList.add` methods.

Your updated JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Check if element contains disabled class
  if (btn.classList.contains("disabled")) {
    // Removes disabled class
    btn.classList.remove("disabled");

    // Adds waves-effect and waves-light classes
    btn.classList.add("waves-effect", "waves-light"); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btnn");
btn.className =
btn.className.replace("btn disabled",
    "waves-effect waves-light btn");
```

As replace with spaces, can only happen on strings.